# Android: half of screen missing when keyboard hidden

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

I have a detail view in which the properties of an item are edited. Those can be name, address and so on. When the screen comes in, then the keyboard is automatically shown to the first TextInputLayout (see first picture).

But when I hide the keyboard with the phones button, then the space remains empty (see second picture). But why? It should actually look like the third picture.

The layout is basically as sketched in picture 4. The three images should be at the bottom of the screen while the content above should be scrollable. As shown in the third picture, the alignment is wrong anyway!?

Keyboard shown:
[image: keyboard shown]

Keyboard hidden - elements behind it are gone!
[image: keyboard hidden]

Keyboard hidden - correct layout.
[image: correct layout]

Layout as defined in XML.
[image: layout]

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:stretchColumns="0"
                    >

                <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                        <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/edit_nick_name"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:hint="your nickname"
                                android:textSize="24sp"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                                />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/btn_scan_name"
                            android:src="@mipmap/ic_camera_alt_white_24dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/action_scan"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                        <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/edit_location"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:hint="your address"
                                android:textSize="24sp"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                                />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/btn_car_set_location_by_gps"
                            android:src="@mipmap/ic_my_location_white_24dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/action_scan"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                        <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/edit_end_time"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:hint="@string/hint_car_ticket_end_time"
                                android:text="17:35"
                                android:textSize="24sp"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                                android:inputType="none"
                                />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                    <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/btn_car_set_end_time"
                            android:src="@mipmap/ic_access_time_white_24dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/action_pick_time"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_car_model"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_car_model"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_car_notes"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:lines="4"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_car_notes"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/car_preview_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/car_preview_size"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/car_preview_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/car_preview_size"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/car_preview_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/car_preview_size"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ItemEditActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please put your xml code.

Comment: of course. sorry, forgot about that. just updated the posting

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.

Comment: Are you sure it's not platform dependent? I've tried your code on Nexus 5 and emulator and it worked fine.

Comment: It does not happen all the time, but very often. Tested on Nexus5 emulator and several real devices. The soft-keyboard pops up when the activity starts.